# Merge data with repeating row with python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, sas

I have found the issue when I try to transform SAS code to python. Supposed I have 2 dataframes, which can be seen below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"monthkey": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['foo','foo','bar']})
```

I want the table look like:

```
monthkey name
1        foo 
2        foo 
3        foo  
4        foo  
5        foo  
1        bar  
2        bar  
3        bar  
4        bar  
5        bar
```

I wrote SAS code below for the reference but how can I use python to create result?

```
proc sql;
create table want as select a.*,b.*from
df as a left join df2 as b on a.monthkey;
quit;
```

Any suggestion on this? Thank you.

Comment: there has to be a monthkey column in df2 i guess..right ?

Comment: @iamklaus no, it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also try using `from_product` in pd.MultiIndex:

```
pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2['name'].drop_duplicates(),df['monthkey']])).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  level_0  level_1
0     foo        1
1     foo        2
2     foo        3
3     foo        4
4     foo        5
5     bar        1
6     bar        2
7     bar        3
8     bar        4
9     bar        5
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below

```
df.assign(foo=1).merge(df2.drop_duplicates().assign(foo=1) ).drop('foo', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'monthkey': (list(range(1, 6)) * 2),
                   'name': ['foo' for i in range(1, 6)] + 
                           ['bar' for i in range(6, 11)]})
```

Using ranges to build one DataFrame made it more straight-forward. [Python datastructure documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) contains information regarding this method.

output:

```
monthkey name
       1  foo
       2  foo
       3  foo
       4  foo
       5  foo
       1  bar
       2  bar
       3  bar
       4  bar
       5  bar
```

Comment: I built separated table and come from other step. In my example, just for illustrative but thank you so much for another solution.